# Can't get the current logged in user's id

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have two tables: users and posts. I made relation between these two tables. When I try to save, the post created by the user to posts to a table. It does not pass the user's id. Please check the below code:

**User Model ( App\User.php )**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    public function posts()
    {
        $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

**Post Model ( App\Post.php )**

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Post extends Model
    {
        public function user()
        {
            $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        }
    }
```

**Post Controller ( App\Http\Controllers\PostController.php )**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Post;
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
    {
        //validation here will come

        $post = new Post();
        $post->body = $request['body'];
        $request->user()->posts()->save();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    }
}
```

**Errors**

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. So, I will post the answer of my question.

I get the current logged in user'id from Auth::id();

So I changed my codes as below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Post;
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
    {
        //validation here will come

        $post = new Post();
        $post->body = $request['body'];
        $post->user_id = \Auth::id();
        $post->save();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    }
}
```

Comment: Or `$request->user()->posts->save($post)`

Comment: Actually, i forgot to add return before eloquent relation. That why i can´t pull out or save with current logged in user´id.